Why can’t acceleration in GR be defined the same way as in EM?
This question stems from page 36 of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler’s Gravitation, where they compare the Lorentz force equation with the equation of geodesic deviation. Specifically, see the second row in the picture.

In EM acceleration is defined through the comparison of the particle's actual world line and a fiducial uncharged test particle. To me, the uncharged test particle is equivalent to a charged particle passing through the same point in the absence of any EM field. Therefore, my question is, why can’t acceleration due to gravity be defined by comparing the actual particle's world line to a test particle passing through the same point when there is no gravitational field? The test particle would effectively be gravitationally “uncharged”.

I don't understand your proposal to define gravitational acceleration "by comparing the actual particle's world line to a test particle passing through the same point when there is no gravitational field." You seem to be comparing world lines in two different space-times, one with a gravitational field and one without. What would such a comparison mean?

In GR, there isn't a unique way to define "a gravitational field."
Let's back up. What MTW are saying is that in GR, to compute the motion of a test particle, you calculate the geodesic in some geometry. To measure acceleration, you need two separated test particles, then you can look at how to the two geodesics converge or diverge (or, stay parallel).
What you want to do is essentially break up the geometry into a "non-gravitational part" and a "gravitational field." This isn't a completely crazy thing to do. In perturbation theory for weak gravitational fields around Minkowski space, for example, we write the metric as $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$, where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is a Minkowski background, and $h_{\mu\nu}$ describes fluctuations in the geometry, which we can call the gravitational field. However, if $h_{\mu\nu}$ is not small, this leads to conceptual issues with the kind of construction you want to do. Why should you take $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ as the non-gravitational reference metric in that case? Even if you think that's a natural choice, there may be global restrictions preventing you from mapping the reference metric to the true metric at every point in the geometry; for example, if you try to use $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ as a reference metric for a de Sitter spacetime, you will find the metrics have different asymptotic behavior (which you can see from the Penrose diagram, for example).
Since the "non-gravitational reference metric + gravitational field" approach doesn't always work, MTW's approach is safer and more general, and more in the spirit of general relativity to consider the whole geometry rather than splitting it up into arbitrary pieces.

In order to answer your principal question at first: How can it be achieved to  study the acceleration due to gravity of a chosen particle compared to a test particle passing through the same point when there is no gravitational field:
Then the acceleration due to gravity of the chosen particle is zero, because the gravitational field is zero (no way out ... both go through the same point, it is impossible that particles which go through same point experience different gravitational fields).
It is all about the pecularity of the equivalence principle that all (heavy) bodies experience the same acceleration. One of the consequences is that accelerations cannot be distinguished from gravitational fields.
To make the difference between a electrical charged particle in an electric field and a heavy body in a gravitational field we change the reference system(also called change of coordinate system in 4D space-time) We change the reference to the rest system of the particle under study. In this reference system the  electrical charged particle under study no longer feels acceleration, but the (differently charged or even uncharged) particles in the neighbourhood  move as if they were accelerated.
However, if the experiment is done in a gravitational field and the rest system of the particle under study in the gravitational field is chosen as reference system, the observer of the rest system of the particle under study will notice that all particles (really all) in the immediate neighbourhood will behave as if there were in a inertial system, so the observer can actually assume that he is really in an  inertial system where there is no gravitational field at all and the original reference system where the particle under study was accelerating was just unfavourly chosen (in the sense of that reference systems where the particles under study are accelerating are not so nice --  the math for the physical description is more complicated and experimental data processing is more complicated too -- compared to inertial systems).
